# Adding additional HTML to a label on select change

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>State / County</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="state_county" type="text" maxlength="50" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Country <strong class="reqstar">*</strong></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="country" onchange="getTelephone(this.selectedIndex)" style="width:257px">
        <option value="UK">UK</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

When I set my `country` select to `USA`, I would like to amend the HTML of my `state_county`'s label.

Required HTML: `<label>State / County <strong class="reqstar">*</strong></label>`

This is the line of code I'm using:

```
$("input[name=state_county]").closest("form-group").find("label").html("State / County <strong class=\"reqstar\">*</strong>");
```

I'm using `closest()` to get to the nearest container element, then using `find()` to get back down to the label, then using `html()` to amend it's contents, but it's not working?

Comment: Is it possible to amend the HTML at all? If so the simplest solution would be to add the `<strong class="reqstar">*</strong>` element with an `id` in to the `label` and hide it. Then toggle it's visiblity on change of the Country select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[name=state_county]").closest(".form-group").find("label").html("State / County <strong class=\"reqstar\">*</strong>");
```

When you're looking for form-group, you need the `.` to indicate you're looking for a class name.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to do the same would be:-

```
$("input[name=state_county]").siblings("label").html("State / County <strong class=\"reqstar\">*</strong>");
```